# I'm looking for a book or short story about mining time from before the mid 1980s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novel

In the book, it is discovered that people can "mine for time" that then can be used to extend their own lives. However, it is discovered that the time you mine is someone else's, and you are actually taking away from their life-expectancy. Anybody familiar with it. My mom read it in high school in the mid 1980s, so it's gotta be from then or before.

Comment: When you say "mine for time", can you be more specific? Are you literally digging time out of the ground or sucking it out of people like a vampire or what?

Answer (score 2):

Although Louis L'Amour was a western author, he was working on a series of short stories that veered from his standard (cowboys and indians) fare at the time of his death.

His daughter (Kathy L'Amour) picked up and finished that last book of short stories and I believe one of those had similarities to your inquiry.

Comment: Is this the book you're referring to? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Haunted_Mesa

Comment: If so, it doesn't look like there's any "mining for time" unless it's buried deeper than the summary. Still, that's interesting. My dad is a L'Amour fan. I'll have to see if he read it.

Comment: Kathy was L'Amour's wife, who ensured that *The Haunted Mesa* got published. His daughter, Angelique, did a non-fiction book of her father's quotations named *A Trail of Memories*, not sci-fi.